# Wordpress store locator HTTP403

Tags: wordpress

[image]

I had installed the plugin WP store locator on this Wordpress site, the first week the plugin works just fine. 
But now it is not working anymore and I get this error (see screenshot above).
I've already deactivate some other plugins but that doesn't seem to work.

This is not only in the Edge browser, but also in Chrome and Firefox.

Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: The 403 error message is basically telling you that the request was rejected by the server (forbidden access). Are you using a security / firewall plugin on your WordPress site?

Comment: I am not using any firewall plugin, I've already asked my hosting but they can't help me with this..